# CodeIgniter with SMTP for Gmail is very, very, very slow

Tags: codeigniter, smtp

I'm using `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` over port `465` with gmail, and when I try to send mail in my `CodeIgniter` application, it just hangs. There's no error and no warning - it literally just hangs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is slow, maybe because of ssl among other things. Try using your local smtp server or sendmail, or evem mail() function instead

Comment: Don't I run into spam issues then?

Comment: What do you address exactly? Why SPAM? You'll probably have hardware limitations of how many emails you can send per time unit (second, minute, hour, day) and other limitations that are put by your hosting provider. Whether your message is SPAM or not is the matter of receiver permission before all. Did you get permission to send then the message etc

Comment: -1 for no code, no logs, no...really anything except a url, port and complaint. Odd how this has (had) +5 votes...

Comment: could be because others have this problem as well? What code or logs would you want? It's basic CodeIgniter email sending.

Comment: Might be. Codeigniter generates logs -- those might be helpful. The email configs might have a typo which could be helpful. `$this->email->print_debugger();` might be helpful....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. After trying to change every possible setting avaible in CI->email I added

```
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

and it worked.

Comment: i've added this one but still getting hangs.. is there a chance that it might be because of slow internet connection speed that smtp requires faster?

Comment: Really doubt it.  I think you would get an exception in this case.

Comment: i already figured it out. and works well. i still do have one problem how to create a multiple smtp_host for other email sites?

Answer (score 0):

From the little information you gave in the question, you're not doing anything wrong.